# app-auth in MS Graph Api does not work in msgraph-training-java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I want to learn MS Graph Api for Java and I'm compiling and running the app-auth example in msgraph training java.

Displaying the access token works fine but displaying the user list fails.

The readme says, when configuring the application permisions I should select "Grant admin consent for..." but there is no such an option. I still get an error:

"Error message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

but I have granted all permissions in the Mail Section and User Section of MS Graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After granting the permission , some permissions need to be granted admin consent in the azure portal as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

You need to ask the administrator for granting the permissions.

Comment: Thanks. This option was missing. I don't know why, my accout was an administrator. I have created a new acount that works now.